# Copy Files from one machine to other using php

Tags: php, hadoop, ssh, rsync, scp

I have setup 2 Ubuntu machines: 192.168.1.104 & 192.168.1.105 have installed ssh on both the machines generated `ssh-keygen` on 104 machine and added key to both the ip-addresses.

I want to copy file from one 192.168.1.104 to 192.168.1.105 through php.
I tried this command `scp /home/tejas/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml tejas@192.168.1.105:/home/tejas/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml`
through shell script the file gets copied perfectly but when I run the same command through php-script

`<?php 
$output = shell_exec('scp /home/tejas/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml tejas@192.168.1.105:/home/tejas/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml');
?>`

It doesnot show any error but file doesnot get copied. Also tried similar with `exec()` and also tried rysnc instead of scp `rsync -avzh /home/tejas/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml tejas@192.168.1.105:/home/tejas/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml` still no luck.

**both the commands are working perfectly through shell script but not working through php**

I checked php is not in safe-mode and shell_exec() or exec() is not disabled in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

`exec()` and `shell_exec()` get executed by the user running the php script (usually `www-data` on Ubuntu but could be `apache` or something else). It's likely that this user does not have permission on the files/folders. One solution is to create a new user Group and add the user (`www-data`) to this Group, then set the proper ownership/permissions on the files/folders to copy/be copied to.

Comment: Will try and post the result

Comment: done `sudo adduser tejas` , `sudo useradd -d /var/www -G www-data tejas` and gave proper ownership to file still doesnot work

Comment: main issue if shell script contains any command like `ls` then it works perfectly. I doesnot work only when copying one  file from one machine to other

Comment: Sometimes it helps to dump the error output to a file. In your `exec` command use something like `exec('scp src dest > /tmp/output 2>&1');` then after running the script check `cat /tmp/output` in a terminal on the machine the script was executed from. It may help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: it shows follwoing error `Host key verification failed.
lost connection`

Comment: Because you're trying to execute the command as `www-data` which probably doesn't have an SSH key created for it. You might look into phpseclib as another option for using SSH in PHP scripts and it will allow you to control which user you execute SSH commands as.